# Blockchain - How can I cancel my blockchain transaction, unconfirmed after +1 day

Tags: blockchain.info, unconfirmed-transactions

I am using blockchain.info.

I have made a bitcoin transaction of 4.79 BTC to the address 1DWaEfPbcKQvjMi9D9eNMrVRQzWiSLVvaS. (exchanger)

You can see the transaction at https://blockchain.info/tx/92f565e23499437ed4d54bc946a044c56353c4d1f512cf514b40a31e49292732

I have paid a 0.0001 BTC fee but it has been almost +24 hours and it still shows "Unconfirmed".

Network Propagation 1% - 18 Nodes - (Very Poor) - Why is so poor the network propagation, what;s to do?

What could be the error? Also, more importantly, how do I cancel the unconfirmed transaction and get back my coins?